# Segmentation fault (core dumped) when launching python in anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, miniconda

When I tried to create a virtual environment using miniconda command 'conda create -n py37 python=3.7', I encountered some problem when I tried to launch python in the virtual environment using command 'python'.

It seems python cannot be launched appropriately in the terminal. The error info is listed as followed:

(py37) bash-4.2$ python
Python 3.7.13 (default, Oct 18 2022, 18:57:03)
[GCC 11.2.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I tried several methods including creating another environment, using the command 'conda clean', even reinstall the miniconda3, but nothing works.

Everything seems to be normal under the python outside the conda env.

Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar issue probably in a completely different context, but try making sure that the python you install is from conda-forge or not the main conda channel. e.g.
`conda create -n py10_test -c conda-forge -y python==3.10`
I found this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to change the LANG environment varialble, e.g

```bash
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Run into the same issue recently on a shared cluster. A user reported that he  failed to open Python via ssh terminal, the `dmesg` log showed:

```
[22458809.093186] python[25221]: segfault at 0 ip 00002aceb37338c1 sp 00007ffd29f52528 error 4 in libc-2.17.so[2aceb35c4000+1c4000]
```

But when I use `sudo -i -u` to switch to his account and run the same command, everything is fine. By comparing the output of `env` in both cases I find that the `LANG` is different. It will fail to start Python if `LANG=C.UTF-8`, which can be fixed by updating to `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`.

It only happens to Python that installed by conda, Python installed by system doesn't have such issue.